# running React with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm running a local environment (Live Server) running React.
I've installed the following packages to make sure the correct operation:

**react 17.0.2**
**react-dom 17.0.2**

I want to run a custom navbar made by me, but it returns the following error from the browser side.

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' main.js 18**

These are the files I am working with:

### main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const navbar = () => 
{
    <div>
        <h1>Computers</h1>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Pricing</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(navbar, document.querySelector(".nav"));
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "project1_staticpage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  }
}
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'/>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'/>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        
    </div>
    <script type="module" src='main.js'>
        
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

I've search the possible issues about this and I found out the interpreter was expecting json, but it received < or HTML.

And it seems that the solution to this is to make sure that the whole javascript script path is correct, although from my point of view it is.

If it helps this is my directory structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH0x6.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the browser doesn't understand JSX syntax, so you need first to transpile `main.js` to a file that can be understood by the browser. Take a look to this [tutorial](https://dev.to/ivadyhabimana/how-to-create-a-react-app-without-using-create-react-app-a-step-by-step-guide-30nl)